# Very long iOS builds on Codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, continuous-integration, codemagic

I have Flutter app with 10-15 dependencies and my iOS builds take up to 50 minutes that sounds quite long comparing to builds on local machine (2-3 minutes).

I enabled [dependency caching](https://docs.codemagic.io/building/dependency-caching/) for

- $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- $FCI_BUILD_DIR/build
- $HOME/.pub-cache

For one of my latest builds pod install took about 300 seconds (less than 10 seconds on local machine) and Xcode build more than 1300 seconds (less than 80 seconds on local machine). Is it fine? What else can be done to increase build speed?

Comment: considering the fact that your local machine can be easily an order of magnitude faster than the build machines (except the mac book pro ones they offers), I think this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174066/codemagic-ios-build-takes-a-long-time-to-complete

Comment: Thank you, saw it. Unfortunately didn't find answers to my questions.